# How can I create an object in NETLink from System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: .netlink

I am using NETLink and I am trying to construct the following .NET object

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

My first question is how can I load `System.Collections.Generic.List`?

The following command:

```
NETTypeInfo[LoadNETAssembly["mscorlib.dll"], {"Classes"}]
```

shows that the class is in mscorlib.  But when I enter:

```
NETTypeInfo["System.Collections.Generic.List"]
```

I am getting an error message:

```
LoadNETType::fail: .NET failed to load type System.Collections.Generic.List. >>
```

On the contrary if I try to load some other class from mscorlib.dll such as:

```
NETTypeInfo["System.Collections.ArrayList"]
```

It works fine.

What I am doing wrong here ?

My second question is how can I create Generic.List type objects with `NETNew`
from `System.Collections.Generic.List` class?

Thank you

PS: I am using Mathematica 10.0 and Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows7 OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just discovered that there is another way to make generic types and there is an advantage in this solution that I am going to demonstrate. I will continue the example offered by WReach, this helped me really a lot to make my first steps as a newby in Mathematica NETLink ;-)

```
$stringListType2=LoadNETType["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"] // GetTypeObject;
NETType["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]", 28]

$stringListObj=NETNew[$stringListType2];

$stringListObj@Add[#]&/@{"xyz","mno","abc"};

$list@ToArray[]
```

How did I arrive to this solution ? 
Well, it is all about NETObject type checking.

Suppose you want to pass the object you created as an argument of a function. How are you going to check if the formal parameter accepts the correct type, i.e. a generic list of strings ? Luckily there is the 
NETLink`InstanceOf function. But according to the definition it accepts either NETType expression or fully qualified class names such as the string I passed to the LoadNETType. So you can type check with the following command

```
NETLink`InstanceOf[$list, "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"]
True
```

Note that if you use:

```
$stringListType = $genericListType@MakeGenericType[{$stringType}]
« NETObject[System.RuntimeType]»
```

That returns NETObject instead of a NETType expression.

And the question that naturally arises is how you get the NETType from the NETObject ? Well, I could not find how, so that is how I discovered the other way around. So, is there a way to get the type of a « NETObject[System.RuntimeType]» ?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated Response**

The internal name of `System.Collections.Generic.List` is "mangled".  We can see what that internal name is by using `NETTypeInfo`:

```
NETTypeInfo[LoadNETAssembly["mscorlib.dll"], "Classes", "*Generic.List*"]
```

[image: NETTypeInfo screenshot]

We can see that the internal name is `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ``.

We can create objects of this type directly with `NETNew` provided we replace the placeholder type name *T* with the actual element type:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

$list = NETNew["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"];

$list@Add["xyz"]
$list@Add["mno"]
$list@Add["abc"]

$list@Sort[]

$list@ToArray[]
(* {"abc","mno","xyz"} *)
```

---

**Original Response**

In .NET, generic types cannot be instantiated directly.  We must first create a specific type that specifies the generic type parameters.  This is done using [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).

First we must obtain a reference to the `List` type.  The NETLink wrapper is not enough -- we must use `GetTypeObject` to recover the native .NET type object:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]

$genericListType = 
  LoadNETType["System.Collections.Generic.List`1"] // GetTypeObject;
```

Note carefully that the internal class name ends with `` List`1 ``, as shown by the information returned by the *mscorlib* `NETTypeInfo` call exhibited in the question.

We then need to load the type for the list elements.  For this example, we will use the `String` type:

```
$stringType = LoadNETType["System.String"] // GetTypeObject;
```

Now we can create a dynamic type representing a list of strings:

```
$stringListType = $genericListType@MakeGenericType[{$stringType}];
```

Finally, we can create a list of strings and operate upon it:

```
$list = NETNew[$stringListType];

$list@Add["xyz"]
$list@Add["mno"]
$list@Add["abc"]

$list@Sort[]

$list@ToArray[]
(* {"abc","mno","xyz"} *)
```